# Magento statuses and states and reviews through kount/braintree (GENE)

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, stock-status, order-state

I'm working on changing various "order states" based on their statuses in magento when they come in via kount Ens.php. I've had some success with a couple of them but I can't seem to figure out the last three.

1. When approved manually the state code needs to change to processing
   instead of payment_review.
2. When declined maually the state code needs to change to holded
   instead of payment_review.
3. When auto declined the state code needs to changed to canceled
       instead of payment_review.

Here's what I have currently:

```
/**
 * Approve an order from Kount
 *
 * @param \Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _approveOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    // Ensure the status has not moved from it's payment review state
    if ($order->getStatus() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW) {

        // Inform the system that this update is occurring from an ENS update
        Mage::register('kount_ens_update', true);

        try {
            $order->setStatus("fraud_cleared");
            $order->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Gene_Braintree_Model_Debug::log('Accept Kount transaction failed to be accepted in Magento: ' . $e->getMessage());
            Gene_Braintree_Model_Debug::log($e);
            return false;
        }

        Mage::unregister('kount_ens_update');
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order approved through Kount.')->save();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Decline an order in Magento
 *
 * If the payment is only voidable, we void the invoice cancelling the order. If the payment has settled we create
 * a credit memo and close the order that way.
 *
 * @param \Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _declineOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    // Ensure the status has not moved from it's payment review state
    if ($order->getStatus() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW) {

        // Inform the system that this update is occurring from an ENS update
        Mage::register('kount_ens_update', true);
        try {
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED, "suspected_fraud_after_review");
            $order->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Gene_Braintree_Model_Debug::log('Declined Kount transaction failed to be declined in Magento: ' . $e->getMessage());
            Gene_Braintree_Model_Debug::log($e);
            return false;
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

---

Here's some things i'm working on to fix:

```
try {
                $order->setStatus("fraud_cleared")
                    ->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
                    ->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Gene_Braintree_Model_Debug::log('Accept Kount transaction failed to be accepted in Magento: ' . $e->getMessage());
                Gene_Braintree_Model_Debug::log($e);
                return false;
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Have you gone through all the error logs including system.log, execption.log and braintree.log ensuring there are no errors or restrictions
- whether whitelisted all IP's and cleared all rules with our firewall to ensure there is nothing blocking us there.
- try using the IP instead of the URL for the ens URL
- Create new API keys & Check user permissions